# Specifing technical debt for custom FxCop rule

Tags: sonarqube

Just as simple as the title expects:

How can I specify the technical debt for a custom FxCop rule. There is no field to enter this, neither in the dialog while creating a new custom rule nor in the dialog for editing it.